# How to implement position responsive patterns in MDC-Web (material-components-web)?

Tags: web, material-components

Tell me please how to use the material-components-web to implement this pattern:

[image: position responsive pattern]

[Link on Material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem as follows:

*CSS*

```
.demo-toolbar {
   margin-bottom: -190px;     
}
```

*HTML*

```
<header class="mdc-toolbar demo-toolbar">
  <div class="mdc-toolbar__row">
    <section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-start">
      <a href="#" class="material-icons">menu</a>
      <span class="mdc-toolbar__title">Title</span>
    </section>
  <div class="mdc-toolbar__row"> </div>
  <div class="mdc-toolbar__row"> </div>
  <div class="mdc-toolbar__row"> </div>
</header>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmwgjQ

Answer (score 1):

@PavelB answer's has a minor problem on smaller screens, namely smartphones. The main section overlaps the content of the navbar.

[image]

Each `.mdc-toolbar__row` has a height of 64px on tablets and smartphones, but on smartphones its height is 56px.

This can be solved using media queries, like this:

```
.demo-toolbar {
    margin-bottom: -192px;     
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
    .demo-toolbar {
        margin-bottom: -168px;     
    }  
}
```

EDIT: here's the [edited pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmqeNr).